# Dictionary item modified before storning

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, runtime-error, copy-paste

I want to copy a filtered column from one worksheet to another. The visible values of the filtered list in sheet "samples" being stored in a dictionary and then copied in sheet "output".

This works well, but I am struggling with a modification of value "quantity" in "samples" column G before storing in the dictionary. The condition is if this corresponding value in column C is equivalent to string "sell" then the "quantity" value must be set as negative (-n).

The below code produces an error "Runtime error 13 - Type mismatch". Any idea how to solve?

```
Sub FilterAndCopy_C()

Dim wsData      As Worksheet
Dim dws         As Worksheet
Dim lr          As Long
Dim x           As Variant
Dim y           As Variant
Dim dict        As Object
Dim i           As Long
   
Set wsData = Worksheets("Samples")
Set dws = Worksheets("Output")

lr = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
x = wsData.Range("G5:G" & lr).Value 'Quantity
y = wsData.Range("C5:C" & lr).Value 'Order type

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    
    If y = "Sell" Then
    dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = "-" & ""
        
    Else
    dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
    End If
Next i

For Each it In dict.Keys
    With wsData.Range("G5").CurrentRegion
        wsData.Range("G5:G" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dws.Range("C2")
    End With        
Next it

End Sub
```

Comment: If the value in "G:G" is `25`, do you want it being `-25` or a simple `"-"`? 1. if the range to be processed is filtered, `x = wsData.Range("G5:G" & lr).Value` will place in the array **all the range, not only its visible cells**. 2. Then, you iterate between `dict.Keys` for nothing. Your code does not use `it` at all. It copies visible cells of **the same range (`"G5:G" & lr`) in the same cell of the other sheet ("C2")**. How such a code could "work well"?  What exactly do you try accomplishing?

Comment: I do not think a dictionary is really appropriate, in the way you use it, for what (I understood) you try doing. If the cells value in G:G are not unique (with the minus sign included), an error will be raised for the same value. Another array will be enough, and its content can be dropped at once in the resized "c2" range of the other sheet. If you love dictionaries, you can proceed as in the code answer, placing the G:G, cells (adapted) value **as items**.

Comment: Usually, these G-column numbers are associated with something like e.g. a product(ID) in another column when you would copy both columns. For the sake of clarity, could you explain why you need those numbers on their own? It is strange, but valid and also doable. Using the dictionary is a little bit 'overkill' i.e. a collection would be enough since there are no unique nor associated values involved. Even better, since you can retrieve the number of cells, you can use it to define an array to hold the values. Sharing the screenshots of your worksheets would do wonders.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that does what I think you want to do:

```
Sub FilterAndCopy_C()

Dim wsData      As Worksheet
Dim dws         As Worksheet
Dim lr          As Long
Dim x           As Variant
Dim y           As Variant
Dim dict        As Object
Dim i           As Long
   
Set wsData = Worksheets("Samples")
Set dws = Worksheets("Output")

lr = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
x = wsData.Range("G5:G" & lr).Value 'Quantity
y = wsData.Range("C5:C" & lr).Value 'Order type

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If wsData.Range("G" & 5 - 1 + i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        If y(i, 1) = "Sell" Then
            dict.Add i, -x(i, 1)
        Else
            dict.Add i, x(i, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next i

Dim k As Variant
For Each k In dict.Keys '1-based
    j = j + 1
    dws.Range("C2").Offset(k - 1).Value = dict.items()(j - 1) '.Items() returns a 0-based Variant array
Next

End Sub
```

No need for a loop + Paste, just a For Each...Next on the dictionary entries to write them on the "Output" sheet is enough.

Comment: `aaa` is not declared and not used in the code after taking the dictionary items array... Instead of the last `For Each` iteration you can simply use :  `dws.Range("C2").resize(ubound(dict.count), 1).value =Application.Transpose(dict.items)`...

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is an issue with line "If wsData.Range("G" & 5 - 1 + i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then" as it causes a runtime error 9 "subscript out of range". If I remove this "if" entirely, the code works for the condition but ignores the autofilter, i.e. it shows all rows instead only the filtered ones. Is there an error in this line?

Comment: The `aaa` variable was a leftover from my tests, I removed it, and I made a correction, you should not have the error anymore. But note that is not really neat...

Comment: Great, almost there! The remaining problem is blank lines in the output sheet, i.e. from filtered rows in the autofilter which should'nt appear in the output sheet. Any way to suppress those rows?